# Leetcode 208 about TRIE. What's wrong with my deconstructor? It never works

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, trie

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Trie
{
private:
    Trie* p[26];
    bool end;
    void clear(Trie* pt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        {
            if (pt->p[i])
            {    
                clear(pt->p[i]);
                delete pt->p[i];
            }
        }
    }
public:
    Trie():p(), end(false)
    {}

    void insert(string word)
    {
        Trie* pt = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)
        {
            int idx = word[i] - 'a';
            if (!pt->p[idx])
            {
                pt->p[idx] = new Trie();
            }
            pt = pt->p[idx];
        }
        pt->end = true;
    }

    ~Trie()
    {
        clear(this);
    }
};
```

I debug in VS and find that every time this line delete pt->p[i] is run, the deconstructor is called again and then call the clear() function recursively.

Moreover pt->p[i] would still point to the same block of memory except that it's inaccessible.

In the discuss section of this problem in leetcode, most solutions build a class TrieNode first so it wont cause problems if one deletes TrieNode but I just wonder if I can get my code work with only one class definition.

Great thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For a given `i`, you're clearing `p[i]` twice.

Once in: `clear(pt->p[i]);`

And a second time in `delete pt->p[i];` which just calls `clear(this)` where `this` is the same `pt->p[i]` from the parent.

You should skip the `clear(pt->pt[i])` call as that's handled by the destructor.

As for the pointer still existing, that's exactly what's supposed to happen. After `delete pt->p[i]`, you can null `pt->p[i]`.

PS: s/deconstructor/destructor/

Comment: Thanks a lotttt @Marc. I have thought abt that for 2 days.